# MSVS Error in for loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, for-loop

I'm getting errors in MSVS at the line below. Any help is appreciated.

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < password.size; i++) {
    bool ok(const string & password) { 
    bool seenUpper = false;
    bool seenLower = false;
    bool seenDigit = false; 
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < password.size; i++) {
        char c = password[i];
        if (isupper(c)) { seenUpper = true; }
        if (islower(c)) { seenLower = true; }
        if (isdigit(c)) { seenDigit = true; }
    }
    return seenUpper; 
    return seenLower;
    return seenDigit;
}
```

Comment: `password.size()` - case solved.

Comment: What errors? I don't see any error messages in your post. Probably be a good idea to _edit your post_ and include them.

Comment: Wait, there's something wrong with unconditionally `return`ing three values in a row.

Answer (score 1):

The [size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) member of `std::string` is a function. You need to evaluate it by appending `()`. It returns a value of type `size_type` that may or may not be signed. You should use the same type for your loop index variable.

Considering that you have 3 consecutive `return` statements, you should also consider increasing your compiler's warning level. It will teach you a lot about your code.